# Сортировка слов по алфавиту СИ

Tags: c, сортировка

Как сделать сортировку слов строки по алфавиту? Где именно - оставил пометку в коде. Желательно без использования сложных функции и т.п (я ещё новичёк)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int onoff = 0;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    typedef struct {
        int num;
        char mess[50];
    } cinfo;
    unsigned num = 0;
    printf("Введите число cообщений: "); scanf("%u", &num);
    cinfo numbs[num];
    char array[num][50];
    printf("0 - сортировка от макс. к мин., 1 - сортировка от макс. к мин., 2 - в порядке ввода: "); scanf("%u", &onoff);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("Номер девайса: "); scanf("%u", &numbs[i].num);
        while (getchar() != '\n');
        printf("Текст(до 60 символов)(слова разделены пробелами или табуляциями): ");
        gets(numbs[i].mess);
        //ТУТ ДОЛЖНА БЫТЬ СОРТИРОВКА СЛОВ ПО АЛФАВИТУ
        
    }
    if (onoff == 1) {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < num - 1; i++) {
            if (numbs[i + 1].num > numbs[i].num) {
                int tmp = numbs[i].num;
                numbs[i].num = numbs[i + 1].num;
                numbs[i + 1].num = tmp;
            }
        }
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < num; j++) {
            printf("Rez: Device: %u ; Text: %s\n", numbs[j].num, numbs[j].mess);
        }
    }
    if (onoff == 2) {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            printf("Rez: Device: %u ; Text: %s\n", numbs[i].num, numbs[i].mess);
            puts("---------------------------------------------");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> желательно без использования сложных функции

Всё очень просто. Используем стандартную С-шную функцию qsort:

> ОПИСАНИЕ
> Функция  qsort()  сортирует  массив  из  nmemb  размером size. Аргумент base указывает на начало массива.
>
> ```
>    Содержимое массива сортируется в соответствии с функцией сравнения, на которую  
>    ссылается compar, вызываемой вместе с двумя
>    аргументами, которые ссылаются на сравниваемые объекты.
>
>    Функция сравнения должна вернуть целое, меньшее, равное и большее нуля для 
>    случаев, когда первый аргумент меньше, равен  или 
>    больше  второго  соответственно.  Если  оба  элемента
>    сравнения равны, порядок их сортировки в массиве не будет определен.
> ```

Вам даже не надо писать функцию сравнения - в стандартной библиотеке С уже есть функция сравнения строк:

> ОПИСАНИЕ
>
> ```
>    Функция  strcmp() сравнивает строки s1 и s2. При этом локаль не учитывается 
>    (для её учёта используйте функцию strcoll(3)). Она
>    возвращает целое число, которое меньше, больше  нуля или равно ему,
>    если выяснится, что s1 меньше, равна или больше s2 соответственно.
> ```